# Can't deselect DLRadioButton radio button

Tags: swift

I'm using [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) but I can't deselect a radio button.

Here I want the user to check either or both of the buttons, but once selected they can't be deselected.

[image: radio buttons]

Comment: Did you set the "other buttons" outlet?

Comment: @Raneem I've added an answer that is working with the DLRadioButton pod.

Answer (score 0):

Make radio button using UIButton

and set selected and default image for UIButtons

Not get actions of both the radio buttons and on click of one change the state of buttons

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to config it without an outlet, without switching to a UIButton.

If you do want to toggle, you can actually set `isMultipleSelectionEnabled` property on the button/checkbox to `true`.